# Mysql & phpmyadmin error

Tags: php, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin

I don't know why I have this kind of error. 
I write all the procedure that I've done. I start my Mysql Database on MAC ( I downloaded it from the site mysql ), then I start XAMPP mysql and apache and I enable the 80 port.
When I insert:

> localhost:8080/phpmyadmin

I have this error:

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Maybe because I have changed something ( I don't understand why ).

My MSQL password is "123456789" and the username is "root".

So I go with the terminal to /usr/local/mysql/bin/ and then I do

```
./mysql -uroot -p
```

and insert my password.

I tried to insert this code:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY '123456789';
```

But I receive this kind of error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PASSWORD('123456')' at line 1

Please help me to resolve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: in terminal command should be `mysql -u root -p` and then enter your password.

Comment: Yes of course, I forget to write this :/

Comment: Your GRANT syntax looks to mix CREATE USER syntax with the IDENTIFIED BY. I'd purge and find a decent tutorial. Try and use `mysqladmin`?

Comment: @ficuscr do you know how can I solve this problem? It's about 3 days that I tried and search on internet.

Comment: @Keyz23 well.. mysql version? Start maybe with SQL: `SET PASSWORD FOR 'ENTER-USER-NAME-HERE'@'localhost' = PASSWORD("123456789");`

Comment: Ahh, crap. carts in front of the horse isn't it... Maybe this will help: https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords

Comment: @ficuscr I have done what you suggest to me and I receive this error:
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PASSWORD("123456789")' at line 1

Comment: Yes, what is your version?

Comment: mysql version is :8.0.11

Comment: Was about to call you a lier but that checks out :) Anyway, just reread the question... Have you configured PHPMyAdmin to use the password? ... `config.inc.php`

Comment: Man i am newbie in this world. I'm trying to learn the connection to database. I can say you what I have done. At the beginning I can connect with no problem to phpmyadmin, but then I have the brilliant idea to change a password of a database ( in phpmyadmin I click on a database that I have created and I changed the password with 123456789, the same password that I use in Mysql ). And after I have done this stupid thing, I have this error.

Comment: I have tried to open config.inc.php on my Mac, but I can't change the password here. I am the administrator of the Mac but I receive always the error that I don't have the right privileges.

Comment: Ahh. I see. This format it's hard to talk you through it. Honestly I might just whack the mysql install and reinstall it fresh. Find a better tutorial on initial setup and adding users. If your only problem is that phpmyadmin does not work I don't actually consider that an issue. Use the command line or download their [GUI tool "workbench"](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/?utm_source=tuicool) and use it if you prefer. Us "pros" shun phpmyadmin ;) As for file permissions... `sudo` ?

Comment: I tried to uninstall everything (mysql and XAMPP) and reinstall but nothing changed! Anyway, thank you! I was trying to create a small site in java and to create a login / registration form I needed a connection with a DB. Have a nice day =)